# AttributeError: 'MultiArrayLayout' object has no attribute 'x

Tags: python, json, rospy

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import json
from custom_msg_json.msg import json_param

#from std_msgs.msg import String



def json_file_reader():

    f = open('/home/arsalan97/ros/sensor_calibration_data.json')
    data = json.load(f)

    for i in data:
        print(i)
    f.close()
    rospy.init_node("json_publisher_node", anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher("json_publisher_", json_param, queue_size=10)  
    #rospy.init_node("json_publisher_node", anonymous=True)
    
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)

    msg = 'Publishing now'
    my_param = json_param()
    #my_param.Translation.x= data['Translation'][0]
    my_param.Translation.x = 10
    my_param.Translation.y = 20
    my_param.Translation.z = 30
    my_param.Rotation.x = [1,2,3]
    my_param.Rotation.y = [2,3,4]
    my_param.Rotation.z = [4,5,6]
```

This is the error I got because I updated `.msg` file and in that I updated `MultiArray` with `vector3` for Rotation variable but I don't understand why is it still taking Rotation variable as a `MultiArray` type.

Comment: Let format your code snippet.

Comment: That would of great help . @DoNhuVy

Comment: @Arsalan9 Welcome to StackOverflow, please take this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71798111/edit) your question to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)